# Can I add an activity in the activity diagram that is not a function in the class diagram?

Tags: android-activity, uml, diagram

I need to add an activity in the activity diagram that is not a function in the class diagram or not a case in the use case diagram>

Comment: Please, formulate better your question.

Comment: I want to add actions in the activity diagram but I don't mention those actions in the operation part of the class diagram of the same project.

Answer (score 0):

You should find a menu Open Activity Diagram when you click on a Class in the class diagram. If you don't it means that this feature has not been implemented by the modeling tool you are currently using.